# Parameter result implicitly has any type

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image]I have a chat app where I'm trying to send notifications for all of the subscribers.  I have to iterate through the users to use the ID's in the where clause to grab their device tokens

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newTopicNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('topics/{id}/topic/{doc}/chat/{chat}')
    .onWrite( async event => {
        const allMessages = event.after.data();
        const db = admin.firestore();
        let data: any;

        if (allMessages) { data = allMessages; }
        const title = data ? data.title : '';
        const topicId = data ? data.topicId : '';
        const groupId = data ? data.groupId : '';

        console.log('incomingData', data);

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'New group topic post',
                body: `${title}`
            }
        };

        let users: any = [];
        let devices: any = [];
        const tokens: any = [];

        users = await db.collection('topics')
                            .doc(`${groupId}`)
                            .collection('topic')
                            .doc(`${topicId}`)
                            .get();

        console.log('users', users.data().subscribers);

        for (let i = 0; i < users.data().subscribers.length; i++) {
            const devicesRef = db.collection('devices').where('userId', '==', users.data().subscribers[i]);
            const device = await devicesRef.get();
            devices.push(device);
            console.log('device', devices);
        }

// here the result keeps showing the error 
        devices.forEach(result => {
            const token = result.data().token;
            tokens.push(token);
          });
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    });
```

Not sure why result has that error but it won't let me upload to cloud functions as a result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the error **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"**?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is specific to the .forEach loop...the 'result' has the squiggly line and when I hover it says, Parameter Result implicitly has any type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it could be a tslint issue. You may need to declare the type as "any" is not allowed implicitly. It has to be explicit.

Try this:

```
devices.forEach((result: any) => {
```